# Delimiter is not shown in table description on hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql

When I do show create table, I see the following delimiter:

> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '

and when I do describe extended table_name, I see:

> parameters:{serialization.format, field.delim})

So is there a way to identify what the delimiter is for the existing table showing the above?

Answer (score 0):

**ROW FORMAT DELIMITED** - that line is telling hive that each new line in a file is a new row

**FIELDS TERMINATED BY** - that parameter is telling hive by what character should be delimited each row. If none is set the default will be used which is ctrl-A

Comment: I am trying to load a file having ^? as delimiter. What delimiter I should use to create the hive table. Any idea?